# tensorflow multi gpu sharing variables

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using multi gpu on tensorflow. And I'm confusing about sharing variable under same scope.

According to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

the easiest way is:

```
for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        // and do sth.
```

But in my understanding, at least the first GPU has to create variable, because it has no variable for it to reuse. And I also find some code which set reuse=False for the first GPU.

So what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. For the first device, the `reuse` flag should be set to `False`. In the tutorial, `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` is called after [construction of the network](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L178). You can do like this too.

Or another possible solution:

```
    for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
            with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse= i>0):
                 // and do sth
```